# Chaining Dependency Injection in ZF2

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2, chaining

I am trying to create a simple email templating test in ZF2, I am using Dependency injection in order to create an instance of the PhpRenderer class, with all the dependencies set.

It appears that I may be struggling with chaining the injections as the path 'email' is not present in the AggregateResolver.

inside module.config.php

```
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'script_paths'  => array(
                    'email' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/email',
                ),
             ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver' => array(
            'attach' => array(
                'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack',
            ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer' => array(
            'setResolver' => 'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver',
        ),
    ),
),
```

inside TestController.php

```
    $di = new \Zend\Di\Di;
    $renderer = $di->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
    $content = $renderer->render('email/test', null);

    echo($content);
```

Message:

```
    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "email/test"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

---

Since writing the above, I was playing around and removed the TemplatePathStack from the di array and this had no effect at all, So I am not sure it is being used at all by the AggregateResolver, so it may be a chaining issue:

```
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        /*'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack' => array(
            'addPaths' => array(
                'paths'  => array(
                    'email' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/email',
                ),
             ),
        ),*/
        'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver' => array(
            'attach' => array(
                'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack',
            ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer' => array(
            'setResolver' => 'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Aborgrove

Comment: At first glance, the `TemplatePathStack` is expecting a parameter key of `script_paths` containing the array of template paths, but you're using `setPaths`

Comment: Thanks Crisp, I have edited the  di accordingly and also in the question above. should the 'options' array be passed automatically into the __construct method of TemplatePathStack? as I am getting a NULL value for the 'options' array inside the __construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved it by moving the di array out of the module.conf.php and recreating it in the Module getServiceConf() method. (Although I am not sure this is the best place to put it)

```
 public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            // using the Session Manger to create one instance of the follwing models
            ......... more code here ............
            'EmailTemplatePathStack' => function($sm) {
                $template_path_stack =  new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack();
                $paths  = array('emailfolder' => __DIR__ . '/view/application/email');
                $template_path_stack->addPaths($paths);
                return $template_path_stack;

            },
            'EmailAggregateResolver' => function($sm) {
                $resolver =  new \Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver();
                $resolver->attach($sm->get('EmailTemplatePathStack'));
                var_dump($resolver);
                return $resolver;

            },
            'EmailPhpRenderer' => function($sm) {
                $php_renderer =  new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
                $php_renderer->setResolver($sm->get('EmailAggregateResolver'));
                return $php_renderer;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Then changing the controller to:

```
    $sm = \Application\Model\ServiceLocatorFactory::getInstance();
    $renderer = $sm->get('EmailPhpRenderer');
    $content = $renderer->render('test.phtml', null);

    echo($content);
```